# SSIS issue accessing entry point in DLL

Tags: dll, ssis, ibm-mq

I have an SSIS Script task (written in C#) that is trying to write to a WebSphere MQ Queue. Obviously we have to reference a specific dll to help make this connection, however I am getting an error involving a separate dll. When the program attempts to open a connection to the queue, the following error appears:

```
{"Unable to find an entry point named 'zstMQGET' in DLL
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\WebSphere MQ\\bin\\mqic.dll'.":""}
System.Exception {System.EntryPointNotFoundException}
```

I found the dll in the folder and tried to add it as a reference, however VS2010 will not allow this. I get an error saying "Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

I should also add that I've downloaded Dependency Walker to inspect the mqic.dll and ran into the following error messages:

"Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found." 
"Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module."

EDIT
The part of the code that is causing an error is an MQQueue object's get() call. Both of these queue types are local, and the Dts.Variables are set accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a result of the code being written for MQ Client 5.3 instead of 7.1. Simply making this change solved our problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry (comment not possible) but what exactly have you changed to get it to run? I have the exact same problem when migrating from 5.3 to 7.1 and cannot find a solution

To make this post more an answer: I was able to suppress this error by using the 3-parameter-call of the GET Function (the one with message size) then the EntryPoint-Error does not occur, but I do not know the exact for it

More Clear: The exact same function call does work later (without any modification) in my program without changing anything, so this is not a permanent linking error

Comment: This was the connection string we used. See that helps: const string ConnectionType = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED;

Answer (score 1):

Have you run the `WMQInstallDir\bin\amqiRegisterdotNet.cmd` script?  For that matter, have you run the vendor install or just grabbed the dlls?

It also makes a difference in what order you install the WMQ and Net components.  Please refer to the [.Net installation topic](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/un10290_.htm) in the Infocenter for more info.

If you need the vendor install media for the WMQ client, it is a free download:

- WMQ V7.0 Client == [SupportPac MQC7](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp)
- WMQ V7.1 Client == [SupportPac MQC71](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp)
- WMQ V7.5 Client == [SupportPac MQC75](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp)

It is advisable to use the latest client version for best performance and stability.  It will work with older versions of WMQ server.  Also, be sure to use the Infocenter corresponding to the version of client you are using!

- [WMQ V7.0 Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp)
- [WMQ V7.1 Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp)
- [WMQ V7.5 Infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp)

Comment: hm... I can't find the WMQInstallDir anywhere on my computer. Can I access this like a normal folder?

Comment: It is usually `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ` but WMQ will allow you to install anywhere, and as of V7.1 even multiple installs on the same host. In this case the registration script should be where you found the dll.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not seem to work. There are three folders inside the IBM dir: SQLLIB_9_7, WebSphere MQ and WebSphere MQ Explorer V7. I ran the .cmd file successfully in all three and the root IBM folder as well, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: What version of WMQ is installed?  You should be able to run `dspmqver` if it was installed from the IBM media.

Comment: The part of the code that is causing an error is an MQQueue object's get() call. Both of these queue types are local, and the Dts.Variables are set accordingly.

Comment: There's a [Fix Pack](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24032120) for V7.1 but none of the problems fixed appears to be directly on point. I'm not a .Net guy and am all out of diagnostics but perhaps Shashi will respond.